# Viewing Mapbox studio map on mobile interface

Tags: powerbi, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, powerbi-custom-visuals, mapbox-studio

While trying to check responsiveness of a Mapbox map on a mobile interface, the following information pops up.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hczdo.png)  [Head to your nearest desktop Computer!, Sorry, Mapbox Studio's style isn't quite ready for mobile device like yours]

Has anyone ever experienced this and have any suggestions on how I can view a mapbox map on mobile browser?

Background: We have a mapbox studio map visual on our Powerbi dashboard with coordinates and tooltips. When the powerbi map is opened in a mobile web browser, the Mapbox map shows as a static image with coordinates and doesn't let user interact or show tooltips when a coordinate is touched/selected. The issue is only when the dashboard is accessed through mobile browser. Works fine on laptops and tablets. I am guessing the attached error has to do something with it, as it works fine (interaction and tooltip) on the same platform when ArcGis map is used with Powerbi. However, we want to use mapbox and would like to resolve this issue. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks!

Per research, the mapbox studio maps should be compatible with web, android and IOS devices.

Comment: you cannot create tooltips in studio - so the map must be configured somewhere else - studio is not the issue here

Comment: and why was this downvoted - I dont understand people